# How can I solve the error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'" when I print graphs?

Tags: python, graph, pyqt, boolean, pyqt6

I'm trying to make a program able to print wafermaps and histograms for each value selected.

To achieve that, I've made one button to show the graphics of the next parameter selected from the list.

The histogram is shown as I want for every parameter, but it doesn't work for the wafermap graph and it shows this error.

```
                                 
    # NEXT PARAMETER
    def next_parameter_analyze(self, data_values):
            widgets.cmbCurrentParameter.setCurrentText("")
            FileName = widgets.txtDataFile.text() 
            result_file = ResultFile(FileName)
            self.measurements = result_file.get_params(list(self.txtParameters.keys()))
            self.actual_parameter=(self.actual_parameter+1)%len(self.txtParameters) 
            par=list(self.txtParameters.keys())[self.actual_parameter]
            widgets.cmbCurrentParameter.setCurrentText(par)
            self.data_value = self.txtParameters[par].replace(" ", "\t")
            estadistica = StatisticsEstepa(self.actual_parameter,self.measurements[par]["measure"],self.config["estepa"])
            
            self.generate_histogram()             #GRAPH WORKING           
            self.generate_wafermap(data_values)   #GRAPH NOT WORKING
```

data_values is necessary to get the values for every parameter, in the histogram graph is not necessary, and it's defined in another function as:

```
# Get data values from result_file
                for fileName in parameters_file_list:
                    self.textoParametros[fileName]=""
                    data_values = result_file.get_data_values(fileName)    #HERE 
                    for chip in data_values:
                        self.textoParametros[fileName]+=str(chip)+"\t"+str(data_values[chip])+"\n"
```

And the get_data_values function is:

```
    def get_data_values(self, name_param):
        # get data values chip + measure for printing in QPlainText
        get_values = dict()         
        for die in self.dies:
            for module in self.modules:
                for param in self.params_list:
                    if param == name_param:
                        measure = self.params[die][module][param]       # get measure value     
                        if not die in get_values:
                            get_values[die] = dict()                    
                            get_values[die] = measure   

        return get_values
```

[image: Program with wafermap (NOT WORKING)]

[image: Program with histogram graph (WORKING)]

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Also: what error?

Comment: The one in the title...

Comment: Then: 1. you should've specified "the error in the title", not "this"; 2. you should provide the full traceback of that error anyway, because without context we cannot know what caused it (especially considering that it doesn't seem caused by any of the codes you provided). We're still waiting for that MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where in your code this comes up but it sounds like you have some variable that is a boolean and you tried to access it like
`somebool.items` and Python is telling you that `somebool` has no attribute `items`